# Accessing State Information of Third-Party/System Application

Tags: java, android, mobile, adb

I am trying to implement a research paper based around state-inference attacks on Android Devices and I am struggling to access the state information of other services running on my device. I am doing so for research in my college to build exercises around mobile security and ethical understanding. My emulator is running a Nexus 5X on API 27 which is directly modeled from the research paper on arm64 architecture.

So far, I have built an `isAppForeground(Context)` method that allows me to determine whether or not a process is currently in the foreground or not utilizing the `ActivityManager` and the `getRunningProcesses()` method. I have come to understand that this vulnerability was refactored to only return the current running process. **Is it possible to obtain a reference to an application and retrieve its context in anyway, perhaps with the package name, PID, or UID? If this is not possible, would it be possible using `adb` to poll a process continually utilizing the `isVisible()` parameter or other parameters I may not be aware of?** Ideally any possible solution would provide me the ability to view state information of a process/application in real-time while the emulator was running. Additionally, the paper touches on utilizing the `IActivityManager` service, which I have come to understand it as a hidden proxy layer accessed via the `ActivityManager`. The paper touches on using its `.isAppForeground()` or `.getAppPendingTransition()` methods to adequately infer a state vulnerability. Any explanation of the differences between the two would be a bonus and greatly appreciated.

My apologies if I did not provide sufficient and necessary information - please let me know what more would help diagnose and solve my problem!

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` may be of help to you. Also `adb logcat events`.